# Should there be an explicit catch-all NGINX `server` block to dismiss HTTPS requests for the domains **not** served by the server?

Tags: nginx, https

The most common NGINX config I see is the one below, where it is made sure that all relevant HTTP requests are redirected and the irrelevant ones are dismissed, but usually I only see one `server` block to handle HTTPS, which is mostly also the implicit default server for all HTTPS requests, regardless of what the `Host` header says. <sup>([Reminder to self.](https://serverfault.com/a/1141180/322755))</sup>

I just learned that, for whatever reason, domain names can get resolved to the wrong IP address, therefore requests can hit the wrong servers (e.g., [1](https://serverfault.com/questions/631364/wrong-ip-address-registering-in-dns), [2](https://serverfault.com/questions/93492/domain-pointing-to-wrong-ip-address-but-dns-records-seems-correct), [3](https://serverfault.com/questions/709694/some-dns-servers-in-the-world-giving-wrong-ip-address-for-our-domain)). According to the HTTPS specification ([RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818), "HTTPS Over TLS")<sup>**1**</sup>, the requested domain must be checked with the domain in the server's certificate (section [3. Endpoint Identification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3)), so the problem of irrelevant requests should take care of itself.

The only reason I can think of in favor of an HTTPS catch-all clause for irrelevant requests is to safeguard against clients with an improper HTTPS implementation (which is always a safe bet).

<sup>[1]: At the top of [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818), it says that it is "*Obsoleted by: [9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110)*". Went there for updates, but the only references to this topic I could find was in section [1.4. Specifications Obsoleted by This Document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#name-specifications-obsoleted-by) that redirects to section [B.1. Changes from RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#name-changes-from-rfc-2818) in [Appendix B. Changes from Previous RFCs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#name-changes-from-previous-rfcs) which simply states: "*None*"...</sup>

```
##################
# HTTP catch-all #
##################
server {
   listen      80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server;

   server_name _;

   return 404;
}

########################## ( see other flavors:
# HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect #   https://serverfault.com/questions/1141066
########################## )
server {
    listen      80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name ourdomain.com;

    return 301 https://ourdomain.com$request_uri;
}

#########
# HTTPS #
#########
server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/signed_cert_plus_intermediates;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/private_key;

    # ... rest of the instructions ...
}
```

---

**edit (2023-08-26)**:

The catch-all block I'm currently using is from the Stackoverflow thread [Catch-all nginx server blocks for invalid subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72600765/catch-all-nginx-server-blocks-for-invalid-subdomains):

```
#############################
# CATCH-ALL (https & https) #
#############################
                                            
server {                                    
    listen      80  default_server;          
    listen [::]:80  default_server;          
    listen      443 default_server ssl;     
    listen [::]:443 default_server ssl;     
                                            
    ssl_certificate     /some/path/any.crt; 
    ssl_certificate_key /some/path/any.key; 
                                                      
    return 444;
    # silently drop the connection
    # ... or you can define some 
    # landing page here instead
}
```

The self-signed dummy certificate and private key is generated via

```
openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -subj "/CN=localhost" \
  -keyout /some/path/any.key \
  -out    /some/path/any.crt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

It's better if the third `server` block is **not** a "default server" as the client's browser will otherwise generate a warning as the server's certificate does not match the requested domain.

You can add a `listen 443 ssl default_server;` to the first server block - you will need to provide an `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key`

You could reuse the credentials from another site. The client's browser will still generate a warning (that cannot be avoided), but if the user clicks through anyway, they will get the return code instead of your website.