# Certbot enables root domain, instead only subdomains

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, docker, lets-encrypt, certbot

I own a domain, lets say example.com.

I want a root domain example.com to be 404 or return a blank page (if 404 is not possible).

sub1.example.com - should redirect a traffic to a running docker container at localhost:3000.

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404;
}

server {
    server_name sub1.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, until I do a `sudo certbot` to generate a certificates (with letsencrypt) and install them + redirect http to https.

In activation process I do only for `sub.example.com`:

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404;
}

server {
    server_name sub1.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.example.com-0002/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.example.com-0002/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = sub1.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name sub1.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Now `sub1.example.com` works fine, but it somehow redirects root domain `example.com` to the same docker container running at `localhost:8000`.

Did I miss something ?

sub1.example.com -> should work
example.com -> should not work

Comment: You only have one `server` block listening on port 443. You should modify the first `server` block so that it listens on both ports 80 and 443. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1141314/316685)

Comment: thank you very much for that detail.